# How to create an array of struct in golang as we create in C

Tags: arrays, go

I want to create an array of `struct` in golang as we create in C. I am trying to create like this, but is not working.

```
type State struct{
    name string
    population string
}st[5]
```

Comment: The number of elements in an array goes _before_, not after, the element type. So that would be `type State [5]struct{name string; population string}`.

Answer (score 2):

Given a definition of a `Struct`

```
type State struct{
    name string
    population string
}
```

You have several ways. You can declare an array of 5 `State`s

```
var states [5]State
```

Or you can assign (and autodeclare) in one line

```
var states = [5]State{}
```

or

```
states := State{}
```

You may want to start from the [Go documentation](https://golang.org/doc/).